# transparent comparators for map::erase

Tags: c++, c++14

The C++14 standard provided transparent comparators for `std::map::find`, `std::map::count`, `std::map::equal_range` and both the upper and lower bound functions: basically, all the functions where key lookup is performed.

Is there some reason that `std::map::erase(const key_type&)` doesn't have a similar overload for transparent comparators?  Was it left out on purpose, or is it simply an oversight?

Comment: There's some discussion in [N3465](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf). One pointed noted there is a potential clash with`iterator erase(const_iterator position); `.

Comment: Note you can get an iterator, then erase at it, with basically no additional run-time overhead.